# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'rolling'

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, numpy-ndarray, rolling-computation

When I am trying to do MA or rolling average with log transformed data I get this error. Where am I going wrong?

This one with original data worked fine-

```
# Rolling statistics
rolmean = data.rolling(window=120).mean()
rolSTD = data.rolling(window=120).std()
```

with log transformed data-

```
MA = X.rolling(window=120).mean()
MSTD = X.rolling(window=120).std()
```

`AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'rolling'`

Answer (score 3):

You have to **convert the numpy array to a pandas dataframe** to use the pandas.rolling method.

The change could be something like this

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data)
rolmean = dataframe.rolling(120).mean()
```

Answer (score -1):

**Try this instead:**

```
numpy.roll(your_array, shift, axis = None)
```

**There is no attribute rolling in numpy. So you shoud use the above syntax**

Hope this helps

Comment: As far as I can see roll just changes the order of the elements in the array. This is not what rolling does, i.e perform calculations on the data